# JavaFX setVisible doesn't update immediately

Tags: java, javafx

I've got a label which is hidden. I want to set it visible, but there is a delay and the label is visible after another instruction. Is there any way to refresh the label immediately?

```
public void foo {
    label.setVisible(true);
    //the label is not visible
    foo2();
    //here the label is visible
}
```

Comment: Is there in the method `foo2()` anything that controls the visibility of the `label`?

Comment: no, it doesn't do anything with the ui

Comment: You could think about to bind the property `visibleProperty` if it makes sense.

Comment: Would you post the content of your `foo2()` method for sure?

Comment: How do you call `foo`. If this does not happen in the UI thread, that would explain the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to your method foo() must happen on the JavaFX application thread otherwise you would get an exception. But this also means that the application thread is blocked for the whole time that your method foo() is running. So how should JavaFX update the rendering of your label if you are blocking the application thread? The rendering can only take place after your method foo() has finished. If the execution of foo2() takes too long, you should execute that on some other thread. See the documentation for concurrency in JavaFX.